# Corrupted MySQL index caused data-loss! How to recover data?

Tags: mysql, wamp

**Introduction to my problem is following.**

A few days ago I wasn't able to start MySQL service in Wamp! Well, I was google-ing a lot to find solution why it doesn't start and some guy suggested to shutdown Wamp, remove one index file and start Wamp again (so Wamp will try to recreate corrupted index again, or something like that)

File I has removed is this one:

```
bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\data\mysql-bin.index
```

OK, after restart I got again green icon in system try and service started working as usual.

Now, that index-file has content like:

```
.\mysql-bin.000029
.\mysql-bin.000030
.\mysql-bin.000031
```

Prior to this error, it has same structure with numbers **000001-000028**.

I'm using Wamp 2.4 (x86) with Apache 2.4.4/MySQL 5.6.12/PHP 5.4.16.

**Problem comes here.**

After that I've tried to access some of my latest php projects and with all of them I'm getting similar error-message in browser.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.tablename'
doesn't exist' in C:\wamp\www\... on line xxx
```

I've started Navicat Premium to see what's wrong and at first look all databases and tables were there (and they still are). Never changed anything with Wamp installation so username and password are still same `("root"/"")`.

Then I realized that tables in databases are just a names in the list. When I try to open any of them I'm getting **error `1146 - Table 'database_name.table_name' doesn't exist`**

[image]

**I DON'T HAVE BACKUP COPY!**

Now I can create new databases/tables and they work but can't use old dbs/tbls. Is there anything I can do to recover those databases/tables. Actually just one database is important because I don't have backup for that one.

I've tried to make `mysql-bin.index` file manually, with all lines (000001-000031) but it still doesn't work. I've tried to find solution all around the web, including StackOverflow and MySQL official website but have not found anything usable. I found some tips but nothing solved my problem or I just didn't know how to follow instructions.

**Update #1**

[Download complete 'data' directory (1.2Mb)](http://service-kl.com/data.zip)

Comment: `mysql-bin` files are binary log files of the events that have happened inside the database. Did your database shut down incorrectly before you noticed this problem? This could cause problems like this. What is the DB engine for your tables? Have you checked that corresponding files exists for the DB engine in your MySQL data directory?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, Most probably that happened because electricity power off while server was working but I can't be sure. DB engine is InnoDB. I don't know what files to look for but if that helps I can export entire tree of 'data' directory with file-names.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, now you can see what I have in `data` dir (update #1).

Comment: Just reach for your backups

Comment: What are the contents for the database directory you want to use? That is, one of the `as011`, `as011xxx` etc.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen, there's `db.opt` and bunch of files with table names (`.frm` and `.ibd`). You can download entire `data` directory (there's link in the question). I don't actually need data, i need just structure so I can recreate tables.